# Trying to run Flask and getting message saying 'ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn''

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pickle

I have two python files. Here is my ml.py file.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pickle
data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\insurance.csv")
le = LabelEncoder()
le.fit(data['sex'])
data['Sex'] = le.transform(data['sex'])
le.fit(data['smoker'])
data['Smoker'] = le.transform(data['smoker'])
le.fit(data['region'])
data['Region'] = le.transform(data['region'])
#independent and dependent columns
x = data[["age", "bmi", "children", "Sex", "Smoker", "Region"]]
y = data['charges']
#split in train and test
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=0)
#model training
linreg = LinearRegression()
linreg.fit(x_train, y_train)
#model testing
predictions = linreg.predict(x_test)
linreg.score(x_test,y_test)
#save the model
file = open("C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\expense_model.pkl", 'wb')
pickle.dump(linreg, file)
```

Here is my run.py file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pickle 
app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open('C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\expense_model.pkl','rb')) #read mode
@app.route("/")
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
@app.route("/predict", methods=['GET','POST'])
def predict():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #access the data from form
        ## Age
        age = int(request.form["age"])
        bmi = int(request.form["bmi"])
        children = int(request.form["children"])
        Sex = int(request.form["Sex"])
        Smoker = int(request.form["Smoker"])
        Region = int(request.form["Region"])
        #get prediction
        input_cols = [[age, bmi, children, Sex, Smoker, Region]]
        prediction = model.predict(input_cols)
        output = round(prediction[0], 2)
        return render_template("index.html", prediction_text='Your predicted annual Healthcare Expense is $ {}'.format(output))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Now, when I try to run run.py in my Anaconda Prompt, I get this error message.

```
(base) C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\run.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ryans\Desktop\run.py", line 5, in <module>
    model = pickle.load(open('C:\\Users\\ryans\\Desktop\\expense_model.pkl','rb')) #read mode
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
```

Sklearn is installed and it works fine when I run it in Spyder. I think, somehow, Flask is not finding the Sklearn correctly. Or, something isn't exposed. Or, rights are not set right. I don't know what's going on with Flask. This is my first time using it. Sklearn is working fine. I know that. Any thoughts on what's wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't imported sklearn in run.py, so it can't unpickle the sklearn objects in your file.

Comment: Kindly refrain from answering questions that are due to typos; leave a comment and vote to close them as such instead.

Comment: I wouldn't consider this a typo, but I will keep that in mind if I see it.